# How to adjust height of div based on content

Tags: css, reactjs

I have designed a reusable ListItem component which I then map over in another component to create a List. The list looks good in an expanded window however when I shrink the window size the text overflows out of the div and onto subsequent items in the list. I am trying to understand how to make it so the height of the list item changes depending on the text inside.

I have searched for an answer and tried the following without success:

1. in #list-item set height:auto
2. in #list-item set height:fit-content
3. In displaying component apply a style of "display:block" to ListItem component during mapping.

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp3ii.png)

[Result of solutions 1 and 2 above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYfK.png)

No difference using solution 3

**ListItem.js**

```
export default function ListItem(props) {

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = (event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id='list-item'>
        <div id="label-container">
          <Typography id="type" variant="caption">{props.type}</Typography>
          <p id="title">{props.title}</p>
        </div>
          <SvgIcon id="icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <ListIcon />
          </SvgIcon>
      </div>
      <Divider id="divider" />

      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>View / Edit</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Add to Community</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Share with...</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ListItem.css**

```
#list-item {
  display:flex;
  width:70%;
  min-height:54px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#label-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#type {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 40px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  top:25px;
  left:10px;
}

#divider {
  width:70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#no-margin {
  margin:0;
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  fill: #70CDE5;
  right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  #list-item{
    width:100%;
  }

  #divider {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Displaying Component**

```
...

{listData.map((item, index) => (
   <ListItem key={item.title} type={item.type} title={item.title} />
))}

...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you have `position: absolute` on your `Typography` and `p`.

When set `position: absolute` to any element it removed it from the document flow, that's why your list height is the `min-height: 54px` only.

Try removing `position: absolute`

```
#type {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#title {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```